# repeater data to pdf in asp.net using Itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, itext

```
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        rptUserList.DataBind();
        rptUserList.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        //htmlparser.Parse(new StringReader("hello world"));
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("btnExport_Click Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
```

I am getting the document has no page. please help.

Comment: You are swallowing all exceptions, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: there is a problem with stringreader because whenitriedcommented part it works sogive mesomesuggestions.

Comment: Ignore iTextSharp for now, iTextSharp is not aware of ASP.Net, grids, repeaters, etc. Also, you are using the very old, deprecated and no longer maintained `HTMLWorker` whereas you are encouraged to use the `XMLWorker`. Back to the problem, you need to inspect  `sr`. That variable **must** hold HTML. Regardless of what you think it holds, you need to inspect and confirm that it actually does. If it doesn't, iTextSharp cannot help you in any way.

Comment: Can you debug and check whether do you have data in sw.ToString()?

Comment: no how can I chk that

Comment: please tell me hw to use xml worker

Answer (score 0):

You should use
 `this.rptUserList.RenderControl(hw);`
instead of  `rptUserList.RenderControl(hw);`